# laravel no post to the sql database no error

Tags: php, laravel, forms

Hy there!
Im trying to create a user for my project.

User.php - model

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','email','password','address','mobile_number', 'department_id', 'designation', 'role_id', 'img', 'start_from'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Department;
use App\Models\Role;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    
    
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $departments = Department::get()->all();
        $roles = Role::get()->all();
        
        return view('admin.user.create', compact('departments','roles'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'firstname'=>'required',
            'lastname'=>'required',
            'email'=> 'required | string | email | max:255 | unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|string',
            'department_id'=>'required',
            'role_id'=>'required',
            'img'=>'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
            'start_from'=>'required',
            'designation'=>'required',
        ]);
        $data = $request->all();
        if($request->hasFile('img')){
            $img = $request ->img->hashName();
            $request->img->move(public_path('profile'),$img);
        }else{
            $img = 'avatar2.png';
        }
        $data['name'] = $request->firstname.' '.$request->lastname;
        $data['img']=$img;
        $data['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
        User::create($data);
        return redirect()->back()->with('message','User-ul a fost creat!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

create_users_table.php

```
   <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('mobile_number')->nullable();
            $table->integer('department_id');
            $table->integer('role_id');
            $table->string('designation');
            $table->date('start_from');
            $table->string('img');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

create.blade.php

```
@extends('admin.layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="container mt-5">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Register employee

            </li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    @if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{Session::get('message')}}
    </div>
    @endif
    <form action="{{route('users.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">@csrf

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">General Information</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>First name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Last name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Mobile number </label>
                            <input type="number" name="mobile_number" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Department</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="department_id" required="">

                                @foreach($departments as $department)
                                <option value="{{$department->id}}">{{$department->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Designation</label>
                            <input type="text" name="designation" class="form-control" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Start date</label>
                            <input type="date" name="start_from" class="form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Image</label>
                            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" accept="image/*" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Login Information</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email </label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Role</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="role_id" required="">
                                @foreach($roles as $role)
                                <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{$role->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach

                            </select>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@endsection
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::post('departments','Departmentcontroller@store');
Route::resource('departments', 'Departmentcontroller');
Route::view('hrmanagement-app','admin.create');
Route::post('roles','RoleController@store');
Route::resource('roles', 'RoleController');
Route::post('users','UserController@store');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

I don't know where is the problem, the other forms are working. Only this one just it's refrash the page and nothing happening -> no post to SQL DB and no erorrs shows.
Please help!

UPDATE

I try the dd() function and the same thing, it refresh the page.

Comment: I'm just commenting about an issue in your routes, as you already put some `Route::resource()` you don't need the `Route::post(Controller@store)` as it's already implied in the resources.

Comment: i've tried comands like php artisan migrate:refresh , migrate:rollback , make:migration. I don't know where to change the code...

Comment: In your form, you call a **route** with the name `users.store`, *(here action = "{{route ('users.store')}}")*, but in your `web.php` file, I don't see any **route** with this name ! That's why the recording is not done

Comment: @Atika it is not "Route::post('users','UserController@store')" this one ? or wich is it?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? If you want to skip the redirect during debugging, just don't perform a redirect

Comment: I comment out the "return redirect()->back()->with('message','User-ul a fost creat!')". It still refrash the page and do nothing. I don't know what to try. please help

Comment: Why not start debugging the problem? `var_dump` and `die` could already help, or using a proper debugger like XDebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **form**, you call a route with the name `users.store`, here :

```
<form action="{{route('users.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

while in your `web.php` file no route with this name. So try to change your route :

```
Route::post('users', 'UserController@store');
```

by :

```
Route::post('users', 'UserController@store')->name('users.store');
```

Normally it should work !

Comment: no results, same flow :(

Comment: I just noticed something else. in your controller, you do an `img'=>'required'`, `$request->hasFile('img')`, but in your form, you called this famous `img` `image`, maybe that prevents the insertion. modify your `name='image'` in your form by `name='img'` And try again...

Comment: Yes, this is it. it's work's and my data post in DB. Thank You!